# What do the unconventional shapes of coffins of Christian burial in some countries signify?

Tags: tradition, burial

Coffins for the burial of Christians are traditionally made either in a hexagonal form  with   tapering at the shoulder point, or in a rectangular shape with proportionate length and width. But, Christians of Ghana are known to be using unconventional shapes of coffins, ranging from those of aeroplane, birds and animals to fruits and flowers. Now, the hexagonal shape reminds us of the Cross, and may actually owe its origin to the Cross. The rectangular shape is good from  practical points of view. But, why the shape of aeroplane and animals? Is it meant to reinforce the idea that a Christian burial is a celebration?

My question in sum is: **What do the unconventional shapes of coffins used in Christian burial in some countries signify?**

Comment: I'd always thought the reason behind the "traditional hexagonal prism" shape was to minimize the size/volume while still containing a prone body, probably because the materials to make the coffin were expensive. This would make sense of coffins being made to fit a specific person (n.b. the cliche of an undertaker measuring someone expected to be killed).

Comment: Exactly ! That is why the tapering starts at shoulder- level . Even the cross is shaped to contain the full human body with hands stretched.  It may thus be coincidental that the hexagonal coffin reminds us of the cross.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What do the unconventional shapes of coffins of Christian burial in some countries signify?**

That wil depend on the individual being buried, as it would seem to be something more in line with what interested the individual during his life before he died.

Another point should be noted is the there is no proof that these coffins were employed in Christian funerals. [Ghana’s population](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghana) is 72% Christian; and there is no link to such [coffins](https://www.core77.com/posts/109535/Unusual-Coffin-Designs-from-Ghana) being employed in any faith based symbolism in religion at all.

These coffins are based on folk culture and not on any religious significance!

Not all coffin designs are traditional or Christian motivated.

> [**Design**](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffin)
>
> Coffins are traditionally made with six sides plus the top (lid) and bottom, tapered around the shoulders, or rectangular with four sides. Another form of four-sided coffin is trapezoidal (also known as the "wedge" form) and is considered a variant of the six-sided hexagonal kind of coffin. Continental Europe at one time favoured the rectangular coffin or casket, although variations exist in size and shape. The rectangular form, and also the trapezoidal form, is still regularly used in Germany, Austria, Hungary and other parts of Eastern and Central Europe, with the lid sometimes made to slope gently from the head down towards the foot. Coffins in the UK are mainly similar to the hexagonal design, but with one-piece sides, curved at the shoulder instead of having a join. In Medieval Japan, round coffins were used, which resembled barrels in shape and were usually made by coopers. In the case of a death at sea, there have been instances where trunks have been pressed into use as coffins. Coffins usually have handles on the side so they will be easier to carry.
>
> They may incorporate features that claim to protect the body or for public health reasons. For example, some may offer a protective casket that uses a gasket to seal the casket shut after it is closed for the final time. In England, it has long been law that a coffin for interment above ground should be sealed; this was traditionally implemented as a wooden outer coffin around a lead lining, around a third inner shell. After some decades have passed, the lead may ripple and tear. In the United States, numerous cemeteries require a vault of some kind in order to bury the deceased. A burial vault serves as an outer enclosure for buried remains and the coffin serves as an inner enclosure. The primary purpose of the vault is to prevent collapse of the coffin due to the weight of the soil above.
>
> Some manufacturers offer a warranty on the structural integrity of the coffin. However, no coffin, regardless of its construction material (e.g., metal rather than wood), whether or not it is sealed, and whether or not the deceased was embalmed beforehand, will perfectly preserve the body. In some cases, a sealed coffin may actually speed up rather than slow down the process of decomposition. An airtight coffin, for example, fosters decomposition by anaerobic bacteria, which results in a putrefied liquefaction of the body, and all putrefied tissue remains inside the container, only to be exposed in the event of an exhumation. A container that allows air to pass in and out, such as a simple wooden box, allows for clean skeletonization. However the situation will vary according to soil or air conditions, and climate.
>
> Coffins are made of many materials, including steel, various types of wood, and other materials such as fiberglass or recycled kraft paper. There is emerging interest in eco-friendly coffins made of purely natural materials such as bamboo, X-Board, willow or banana leaf. In the latter part of the 19th century and the early part of the 20th century in the United States, glass coffins were widely sold by travelling salesmen, who also would try to sell stock of the companies making the coffins.
>
> Custom coffins are occasionally created and some companies also make set ranges with non-traditional designs. These include printing or painting of peaceful tropical scenes, sea-shells, sunsets, cherubim, and patriotic flags. Some manufacturers have designed them to look like gym carry bags, guitar cases, cigar humidors, and even yellow dumpster bins. Other coffins are left deliberately blank so that friends and family can inscribe final wishes and thoughts upon them to the deceased. In Taiwan, coffins made of crushed oyster shells were used in the 18th and 19th centuries.[citation needed] In the 1990s, the rock group Kiss released a customized Kiss Kasket, which featured their trademark makeup designs and KISS logo and could also be used as a cooler. Pantera guitarist Dimebag Darrell was buried in one.
>
> **Design coffins in Ghana**
>
> Design coffins in Ghana, also called fantasy coffins or figurative coffins, are only made by specialized carpenters in the Greater Accra Region. These colourful objects, which are not only coffins, but considered real works of art, were shown for the first time to a wider Western public in the exhibition Les Magiciens de la terre at the Musée National d’Art Moderne in Paris in 1989. The seven coffins shown in Paris were done by Seth Kane Kwei (1922–1992) and by his former assistant Paa Joe (b. 1947). Since then coffins of Kane Kweis successors Paa Joe, Daniel Mensah, Kudjoe Affutu or Eric Adjetey Anang and others have been displayed in many international art museums and galleries around the world. The design coffins of the Ga have long been celebrated in the Western art world as the invention of a single, autonomous artist, the coffin maker Kane Kwei (1924–1992) of Teshie. But as Regula Tschumi shows with her recent research this assumption was false. Design coffins have existed already before Kane Kwei and other Ga carpenters like Ataa Oko (1919–2012) from La have built their first figurative coffins around 1950.  Kane Kwei and Ataa Oko had only continued a tradition that already existed in Accra where the kings were using figurative palanquins in the forms of their family symbol. And as those chiefs who were using figurative palanquins had to be buried in a coffin looking like their palanquin, their families used figurative coffins which were formerly nothing else than the copies of the design palanquins. Today figurative coffins are of course no more reserved for the traditional Ga and their kings, many families who use figurative coffins are indeed Christians. For them design coffins have no longer a spiritual function, their appeal is more aesthetic, aimed at surprising mourners with strikingly innovative forms like automobiles or aeroplanes, fish or pigs, onions or tomatoes. So the figurative coffins, rather than constituting a new art form as it was long believed, were developed from the figurative palanquins which had existed already a long time.

Traditional distinctions can be commonly drawn up between ***coffins"*** and ***caskets***, using ***coffin"*** to refer to a tapered hexagonal or octagonal (also considered to be anthropoidal in shape) box and ***casket*** to refer to a rectangular box, often with a split lid used for viewing the deceased as seen in the picture.
In the Middle Ages, the deceased other than the wealthy or well known individuals were commonly buried in a simple sheet. You can see this in movies that are somewhat historically accurate.